# How to pass variable values from an included file to class properties

Tags: php, class, methods, properties, html-email

I'm having an issue where Sender name, Subject and Sender Email address are empty when I use values from the template function, but if I directly write the email and subject in the mail function they appear.

**EDIT**

**What I am trying to do**

**1**. Create email templates that can be switched depending on the type required as specified like.

```
 $type  = 'account_verify';
 $email = new email($type);
 $email->send('user@domain.com');
```

**2**. Have a method that switches these templates based on $type. 
I want all the parameters like, "subject", "from_email", "sender_name"... to be specified in every template so that I only call the $email->send('user_email') method with the user email only, the rest of those parameters should be found on the specified template.

**See template method below.**

Ok here's how every template looks.

```
<?php 
    $token              = self::token();
    $user               = self::user();
    $today              = date("M j - Y, g:i a");
    $verify_link        = ""
    $from_email         = 'department@domain.com';
    $sender_name        = 'department Name';
    $department_name    = 'department';
    $subject            = 'Verify your account';
    ob_start();
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    ..........
<?php  

 ?>
```

**The rest is as follows**

```
            public $senderName;
            public $from_email;
            public $dpt;
            public $type;
            public $subject;

private function template(){

       include_once 'templates/accounts/account_verify.php';

         //// the following variable like, "$from_email", are set inside the
        ///// included template. Every template should have its own
       /////// parameters set.

            $this->from_email   = $from_email;
            $this->senderName   = $sender_name;
            $this->dpt          = $department_name;
            $this->subject      = $subject;
            return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And the function that sends the email

```
public function send($to_email ,$color_scheme = NULL){

                    var_dump('SUBJECT           : '.$this->subject);
                   ///// here if I dump the $this->subject i can see it, 
                   //// but the subject is empty on the email. 

                    $subject     = $this->from_email;
                    $from        = "".$subject."<user@domain.com>";
                    $headers     = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
                    $headers    .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                    $headers    .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                    mail($to_email,$this->subject,self::template(),$headers);

}
```

Comment: Class methods will not take values like this. Define those values as constants and use it in the class method.

Comment: @EdwinAlex, I won't be able to change constants at runtime from template();

Comment: Obviously, your class lacks class keyword and name...

Comment: Why did you decide to not use one of the PHP `templating classes`? I use one that uses `PHP`  as the templating language. They have already done all the hard work for you. e.g, [Plates is a native PHP template system that’s fast, easy to use and easy to extend.](http://platesphp.com/engine/). Also there is  `Twig`.

Comment: @RyanVincent It's the first time I'm trying to do this. Can you please put an answer suggesting how using that Template Engine would simplify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to your problem is object oriented programming. Structure your include file into a class that you can initialize right after you include it. You will then be able to access all the properties you're trying to get either directly (if they're public), or through some get methods. You can also then do away with the output buffering by putting the template html into another get method.  Something like...

```
 return $templateObj->getHTML();
```

Make the class in each template the same so, or name it after the type to simplify your class initialization.

```
$templateObj = new Template();
//or
$templateObj = new $YourTemplateName();
//where $YourTemplateName == "Account_Verify" or whichever template you're loading
```

Comment: How do I pass the parameters from the template to the email class using this approach?

Comment: Declare the class in the included file immediately after including it. You will then have scope to the class contents. You'll then be able to assign them to the email class just like you have now except more like $this->from_email = $templateObj->from_email;